# Error "Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services"

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-play-services

(translated with Google translator) I searched the Internet, everywhere people just change the version in build.gradle. Help me please. **I'm ready to update the gms plugin, but how do I do this?**

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.1.

My project gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:14'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

into this:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

to avoid the mixing version error.

Also update the firebase-core dependency into this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Answer (score 3):

You can update versions of google libraries from this
[https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup](http://link)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using ionic Cordova and fixed it by changing the GMS version in platforms/android/project.properties

```
 "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {
      "GMS_VERSION": "VERSION_NUMBER_MENTIONED_IN_THE_BUILD_ERROR"
```

and in platforms/android/android.json

```
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics: VERSION_NUMBER_MENTIONED_IN_THE_BUILD_ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as follow

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    ...
}
```