# error while using firebase push notification

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, push

How to fix it my error. I integrated google service plugin in my gradle file and also added firebase push notification API in compile section. But when i compile i get an error in support appcompat.

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')


compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51270635/error-please-fix-the-version-conflict-either-by-updating-the-version-of-the-goo)

Comment: Please post your error log.

Comment: please share module app build.gradle file and project build.gradle file

Comment: please share the whole error which you are getting